# I would like to sort the particular column

Tags: sorting

I want to sort these number

36 ms
4 ms
44 ms
8 ms

like this

4 ms
8 ms
36 ms
44 ms.

using the sort command in linux. Thanks

16:59:52.092 - 16:59:52.121   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   29 ms

16:59:51.940 - 16:59:51.943   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   3 ms

16:59:52.092 - 16:59:52.130   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   38 ms

16:59:52.029 - 16:59:52.068   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - 
PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   39 ms

16:59:52.092 - 16:59:52.133   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   41 ms

17:59:34.248 - 17:59:34.253   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   5 ms

18:14:39.263 - 18:14:39.268   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   5 ms

19:41:59.355 - 19:41:59.360   PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationRequestFDD - PhysicalSharedChannelReconfigurationResponse   5 m

Comment: SHOW YOUR WORK.  What did you try to do, and what specific problems did you encounter?  We can't help you with the way the question is right now.

Comment: I have tried sort command with different combination and I also google it but I could get the right command.
I want to sort the 5th column and complete digit not only sort on the basis of first number of the digit.

I have tried theses commands.
sort -k5
sort -k5 -n
sort -k5n,3

Answer (score 1):

`echo '36 ms 4 ms 44 ms 8 ms' | xargs -n 2 | sort -n -k1 | tr '\n' ' '`

does the trick using UNIX sort, but you have to pass through the intermediate steps of splitting and re-composing the input

Comment: Actually I missed the input you posted, in that case you can use something like `YOUR INPUT | awk '{print $7,$8}' | sort -n | xargs ` on your input to get the expected result